# How to pass array to function

Tags: excel, vba

I try to pass array to function in VBA EXCEL. I cannot find proper example as I try to do

I try to pass array to function
In function declaration
I try set variable array as variant or ByRef but not work
What's I am wrong?

```
Dim Retarray(1 To 6, 1 To 2) As String
```

This is my array
Then try to pass to function as

```
Smap = checkDevNo(Retarray, Right(CellArray(i, 1), 1))
```

This is my function declaration

```
Function checkDevNo(ByRef aaray() As String, aa As Character) As String

Select Case aa

Case "1"
    For j = 1 To 6
        If aaray(j, 1) = 6 Then
            checkDevNo = j
        End If
    Next j
Case "2"
    For j = 1 To 6
        If aaray(j, 1) = 7 Then

        End If
    Next j
End Select
End Function
```

compile error user define type not define ??

Comment: The editor is highlighting the word `Character` as it warns about the user-defined type not being defined...

Comment: Note that `ByRef` is the implicit default: both parameters of that function are passed by reference. One explicitly, the other implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, `Character` is not a VBA type. You should pass it as `String` or `Byte` instead. In Visual Basic, single characters can also be stored in fixed-length strings (`Dim myChar As String * 1`), but that syntax is not supported for method parameters.

So your function declaration should look like this:

```
Function checkDevNo(ByRef aaray() As String, aa As String) As String
    ...
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking Excel VBA, then you'll need to do the following:

```
Function checkDevNo(aaray As Variant, aa As String) As String

    Select Case aa

        Case "1"
            For j = 1 To 6
                If aaray(j, 1) = 6 Then
                    checkDevNo = j
                End If
            Next j
        Case "2"
            For j = 1 To 6
                If aaray(j, 1) = 7 Then

                End If
            Next j

    End Select

End Function
```